# Emacs/Evil mode - how can I set TAB to cycle buffers?

Tags: emacs

I would like to configure my Emacs/Evil so that when in normal mode (i.e. after hitting ESC and navigating inside the file) then the TAB key switches to the next buffer, and Shift-TAB switches to the previous one. I tried this in my .emacs ...

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "\t") 'evil-next-buffer)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "S-\t") 'evil-prev-buffer)
```

...but it didn't work.

Since that motion is muscle-memoried in my fingers, I'd appreciate any help on making this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<tab>` to set a tab binding. Try these commands instead.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<tab>") 'evil-next-buffer)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'evil-prev-buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried it, and: (a) it doesn't work in text mode emacs (`emacs -nw`) where TAB inserts the TAB character (b) In graphics mode, things are better: TAB does what I want, but S-TAB emits: "<backtab> is undefined"

Comment: @ttsiodras - Odd. I swear `<S-tab>` worked for me earlier. I updated it, so it should work at least in graphics mode now.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I am currently stuck in graphics mode anyway (ensime debugger doesn't work properly in text mode).